# How do I make a villager trade items with lore and a name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So all ive tried alot of things but i'm not good with commands

```
summon villager ~ ~ ~
{
  VillagerData: {
    profession:weaponsmith,
    level:5,
    type:swamp
  },
  Invulnerable:1,
  Silent:1,
  NoAI:1,
  CustomName:"\"Bounty board\"",
  Offers: {
    Recipes: [
      {
        buy: {
          id:"minecraft:Arrow",
          Count:1b,
          tag: {
            display: {
              Name:"hercules bow",
              Lore: ["This item is one of a kind"]
            }
          }
        },
        sell: {
          id:"diamond block",
          Count:1
        },
        rewardExp:0b,
        maxUses:1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working but could someone help me

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple syntax errors. Here is a working command, made with a [command generator](https://mcstacker.net/):

```
/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {VillagerData:{profession:weaponsmith,level:5,type:swamp},Invulnerable:1,Silent:1,NoAI:1,CustomName:'{"text":"Bounty Board"}',Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"minecraft:arrow",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"hercules bow"}',Lore:['{"text":"This item is one of a kind"}']}}},sell:{id:"minecraft:diamond_block",Count:1b},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:1}]}}
```

Here are the errors your command contained:

---

```
/summon villager ~ ~ ~{VillagerData
...
```

There should be a space between the `~` and the `{`.

---

```
...
CustomName:""Bounty board""
...
```

This should be in JSON formatting, like so:

```
CustomName:'{"text":"Bounty Board"}'
```

---

```
...
Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"minecraft:Arrow",
...
```

`"minecraft:Arrow"` should not be capitalized.

---

```
...
tag:{display:{Name:"hercules bow",Lore:["This item is one of a kind"]}}}
...
```

The name and lore should be in JSON formatting, like so:

```
tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"hercules bow"}',Lore:['{"text":"This item is one of a kind"}']}}}
```

---

```
...
sell:{id:"diamond block",Count:1}
...
```

There should be an underscore in the item id, like this: `"diamond_block"`